# Why is it legal to have conflicting names for associated generic types in rust?

Tags: rust

I find that I convert trait generics:

```
trait Foo<TItem> {
    fn clone(&self, item: TItem) -> TItem { 
        item.clone() // <-- ah, it needs + Clone
    }
}
```

...into associated types:

```
trait Foo {
    type TItem : Clone;
    fn clone(&self, item: Self::TItem) -> Self::TItem {
        item.clone()
    }
}
```

Reasonably often. However, today I made a typo when doing this, and as a result I got:

```
trait Foo<TItem> {
    type TItem : Clone;
    fn clone(&self, item: TItem) -> TItem {
        item.clone()
    }
}
```

Which results in an error:

```
1 | trait Foo<TItem> {
  |           ----- method `clone` not found for this type parameter
...
item.clone()
     ^^^^^ method not found in `TItem`
```

In this case, the error is obvious, but in some cases, the error reporter cannot resolve the related generic, resulting in more obscure errors such as this real-world example:

```
error[E0599]: the method `clone` exists for struct `Vec<TItem>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
191 |         let b = matched.1.clone();
    |                           ^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Vec<TItem>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
```

So, long story short, yes, I know that `TItem` and `Self::TItem` are distinct types and can be referenced separately, however, what I *don't* understand is why this possible.

Wouldn't it make sense for `Self::X` and `X` to share a common namespace and result in `previous definition of the type 'TItem' here`?

Have I over looked something? Is there any use-case for `Self::Foo` and `Foo` to both exist on a trait? ...or is this just a legacy thing, that exists for compatibility reasons?

To try to make this a more specific and concrete question, [the original RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0195-associated-items.md#namespacingshadowing-for-associated-types) says:

```
struct Foo { ... }

trait Bar<Input> {
    type Foo; // this is allowed
    fn into_foo(self) -> Foo; // this refers to the trait's Foo

    type Input; // this is NOT allowed <------------
}
```

However, this is legal now, as you can see from this play link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=92f9b44c30d44192a77cac8ffee5d142

What changed?

I'll accept any answer that can point me to an RFC / discussion that indicates why the accepted RFC is no longer correct.

Comment: It's probably not much different to how you can declare `let x = 5; let x = 6;` in the same scope, with the second variable hiding the first.

Comment: @kaya3 no, `Self::Foo` and `Foo` are distinct types. If you repeat `type Foo` you get `previous definition of the type 'Foo' here`; it's obviously a deliberate choice to allow them to both exist at the same time.

Comment: Those two variables named `x` are also distinct; they have different memory locations and you can retain a reference to `&x` (for the first variable) even after declaring the second one. Types declared with `type`/`struct`/`enum` are unordered so it's an error to declare multiple in the same scope with the same name like that, but a type in one scope can have the same name as a type in an outer scope, hiding it, and that's not an error. I don't think it necessarily follows that a deliberate decision was made to allow this when it's a generic type parameter and an associated type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wouldn't it make sense for `Self::X` and `X` to share a common namespace and result in previous definition of the type `TItem` here?

Yes, it would make sense on first glance, and that was originally the plan. You can find proof of that from the RFC itself which has this example code:

```rust
trait Graph {
    type N;
    type E;
    fn has_edge(&self, &N, &N) -> bool;
}
```

Note how `Self::N` is not used.

You can also find proof of that in comments from Rust core team members such as Niko who made comments like [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/16377#issuecomment-55658583):

> Instead one ought to write `T`, `Self::T` or (maximally explicit) `<Self as Foo>::T`.

Note how `T` is talked about as equivalent to `Self::T`.

> What changed?

After the RFC was accepted, it was decided to NOT allow plain `T` to refer to associated types, because it would lead to a lot of tricky ambiguity problems that would have to be solved. You can find the full discussion [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18764), where you find this at the end (also by Niko):

> For the record I feel...fairly uncomfortable with a scoping rule that puts assoc type resolution as a fallback [to regular generic type parameters].

In other words: "if we allow this, we need to solve several tricky follow-up problems". And then follows the decision to require `Self::`

> We decided at the weekly meeting today that we would stick with requiring `Self::` rather than implementing this shorthand.

### Summary

The implementation of associated types was never "complete". Instead, it has been done in smaller incremental steps. See for example [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/16377#issuecomment-52049968) comment from one of the implementors of associated types:

> This patch is already huge so I'd like to implement that in a followup.

Because of the incremental nature of implementing support for associated types, and because of the decision to deviate from the original RFC, it is currently possible to have both a generic type parameter named `T` and an associated type named `T`.

Answer (score 1):

The names don't conflict.  Your second code snippet doesn't compile, which illustrates that:

```
error[E0412]: cannot find type `TItem` in this scope
 --> src/lib.rs:3:27
  |
3 |     fn clone(&self, item: TItem) -> TItem {
  |                           ^^^^^ help: you might have meant to use the associated type: `Self::TItem`
```

The associated type is `Self::TItem` and the generic type is `TItem`. They cannot be used interchangeably, and one cannot mean the other.  There is therefore no reason to disallow them to have the same name.

Comment: The original RFC says this should be illegal because it shadows the trait type parameters; so clearly there *is* (or was) a reason (ie. it's confusing) for this? I don't think it's fair given that a) it was part of the RFC or b) I clearly explained in my question that in some circumstances the error messages make the error unclear, to say "There is therefore no reason to disallow them to have the same name.". I'm not sure why this answer is upvoted; it's doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Doug It addresses the question by addressing an incorrect assumption/conclusion in the question, namely that the names conflict. They don't.

Comment: respectfully, my question is "Why is this legal, the RFC says it should be *illegal*?" and your answer is "It is legal". You appear to have answered the title of the question without reading the actual question? I'm sorry if the title is misleading, feel free to change it if you think it's unclear. However, my question does not have an invalid assumption in it; I've been extremely clear and detailed in the question.

Comment: @Doug It's not just the title. The second code block appears to illustrate that the names do conflict, but it does not even compile on Rust. If you correct this code block to successfully compile then you will see that there isn't a conflict. As far as what changed, Rust doesn't have a formal specification and not every change requires an RFC. I'm not sure there is an RFC for this change; if there were, it would be between RFC 195 and 1598. (And, it looks like the verbiage in the question referencing the RFC was introduced _after_ I posted my answer.)